# ¿Como hacer un modulo de cambio de contraseña en Mongodb, passport y nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, passport

Hola buenos dias estoy haciendo un proyecto con un logeo y registro pero tengo el problema que he estado probando unos modulos de cambio de contraseña pero ninguno me ha funcionado aca les dejo el codigo donde tengo el modelo y el passport por si me pueden ayudar:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

const { User } = require('../models');

passport.serializeUser((newUser, done) => {
  done(null, newUser.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
  const newUser = await User.findById(id);
  done(null, newUser);
});

passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password',
  tallerField: 'taller',
  nombreField: 'nombre',
  passReqToCallback: true
}, async (req, email, password, done) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({'email': email})
  console.log(user)
  if(user) {
    return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'The Email is already Taken.'));
  } else {
    const newUser = new User();
    newUser.email = email;
    newUser.taller = req.body.taller;
    newUser.nombre = req.body.nombre;
    newUser.password = newUser.encryptPassword(password);
  console.log(newUser)
    await newUser.save();
    done(null, newUser);
  }
}));

passport.use('local-signin', new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password',
  passReqToCallback: true
}, async (req, email, password, done) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({email: email});
  if(!user) {
    return done(null, false, req.flash('signinMessage', 'No User Found'));
  }
  if(!user.comparePassword(password)) {
    return done(null, false, req.flash('signinMessage', 'Incorrect Password'));
  }
  return done(null, user);
}));
```

ese el passport que uso para el modulo de logeo y registro y este es el modelo de mongoose:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
  taller: String,
  nombre: String,
  telefono: Number,
  foto: String
});

userSchema.methods.encryptPassword = (password) => {
  return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10));
};

userSchema.methods.comparePassword= function (password) {
  return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
```

este es modelo que tengo y tambien uso un encriptamiento de contraseña me seria de bastante ayuda que me pudieran ayudar o poder brindar una solucion a este problema que tengo muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿A qué le llamas *módulo de cambio de contraseña*? La lógica para que un usuario registrado en tu sistema pueda cambiar su contraseña, la escoges tú de acuerdo a los casos de uso. Existen 2 posibilidades: cambio porque el usuario no la recuerda, en ese caso se dice que la contraseña se restablece, y cambio porque el usuario decide cambiarla. ¿Qué es lo que necesitas hacer exactamente y dónde tienes problemas? Saludos

Comment: Hola mauricio lo que quiero hacer es que cuando ingrese un persona tenga la posibilidad de cambiar su contraseña y la base de datos sea editada

Comment: Entonces edita tu pregunta y agrega lo que hayas intentado, porque tal como tu pregunta está, se basa en opiniones y es muy amplia. Saludos

Comment: oka gracias por la critica. Saludos